# How to catch exceptions thrown by UseDeveloperExceptionPage in asp.net core?

Tags: asp.net-core, exception

I'm using Dapper with a custom SqlMapper.TypeHandler for handling Uris. Whenever the Uri is not well-formed, the Parse method in the custom handler throws System.UriFormatException, which I expect to bubble up, caught by the UseDeveloperExceptionPage and displayed on the browser. But all I get is an empty page.

Looking at the VS stack trace, the following line seems to indicate the problem, but I don't know how to get around it:

*Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware: Error: An exception was thrown attempting to display the error page.*

When I use my custom exception handler, app.UseExceptionHandler("error"), I'm able to display the error.

This is the only relevant discussion I could find, https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/3301, which was closed last year without a resolution.

Comment: Unfortunately you are out of luck - the developer exception page middleware is very much a "black box" with no extension points and very obscure/difficult-to-follow code. I would suggest submitting a new issue to their repo that links to that closed issue, and explaining exactly what you've done to manage to cause the breakage.